# Which server for retrieving data?

Tags: java, android, client-server

I have some experience in Android. I have made few applications and I have better understanding of Android programming every day. Since I'm teaching myself i have come across a problem and I hope you guys can help me.

I want to build very simple application which will only fetch some data from server and display it to the user (Something similar to news application ). So when i update info on my server the client will also have updated content on his android phone.

Question:
Which server do i need and how to update my content on my server so client will also have updated content when will start the application?

I know about getting data from the server (JSON).
So can anyone point me to some good reading about what I've asked or something. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PHP with mySQL. A good starting point will be http://www.youtube.com/course?list=EC442FA2C127377F07 . However note that this PHP is going to be depreciated soon. You can use a simple webserver, by simple webserver I mean the one you use to upload your website to, alternatively you can turn your machine into a server too but this is not recommended.

The flow will be:

Java ~~~> PHP ~~~> mySql. (Request)

mySql ~~~> PHP ~~~> JSON ~~~> Java. (Response)

Alternatively if all that you want to display is Headlines and news items, you can go for XML method, wherein you host a page with XML content and parse that in your application.

Here is a nice example: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/